# How to copy values from table A to B and inserting reference to B in A?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to copy values from `a_table.foo` to `b_table.bar` and insert the generated `b_table.id` to `a_table.b_id`:

```
WITH b_inserts AS (
  INSERT INTO b_table (bar)
  SELECT foo
  FROM a_table
  RETURNING id as b_id, a_table.id as a_id
)

UPDATE a_table
SET b_id = b_inserts.b_id
FROM b_inserts
WHERE a.id = b_inserts.a_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/13819/1

It fails because I cannot return `a_table.id` from `b_inserts` as it's not part of the inserted row which is all `RETURNING` can access.

Is there a way to solve this without having to create a temporary `b_table.a_id` column?

Comment: Why are you trying to do an insert and update in a single statement?  Even if this could be made to work, it seems confusing.  Why not do the insert and update separately?

Comment: Link seems didn't work

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm open to solutions achieving it in multiple statements. I just don't see how that would work as the mapping between A and B is lost after the insertion (unless you add a temporary `b_table.a_id` column which I would like to avoid if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the mapping before you do the insert:

```
WITH a_to_b_mapping AS (
  SELECT nextval('b_table_id_seq'::regclass) b_id, foo, id AS a_id
  FROM a_table
), b_inserts AS (
  INSERT INTO b_table (id, bar)
  SELECT b_id, foo
  FROM a_to_b_mapping
  RETURNING id
)
UPDATE a_table a
SET b_id = m.b_id
FROM a_to_b_mapping m
  JOIN b_inserts i ON i.id = m.b_id
WHERE a.id = m.a_id
```

Note that you need to join to `b_inserts` in update to make sure that insert happens first in case you have a foreign key from `a_table.b_id` to `b.id`.

Comment: Interesting solution! Can't quite get it to work though. All `a_table.b_id` turn out the same and I can't figure out why... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/13819/7

Comment: I've updated the query. This one works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e56f2e/55